# zsh auto completion certain parts of directory

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I currently have `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'` which will ignore the case when auto completing directories. However is it possible to type a certain part of the directory and it will attempt to auto complete?

For example
If it type `ocum` it will auto complete to `Documents` or `eskt` it will complete to `Desktop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow correction if completion is not possible, and also set `autocd` if you just want to write `ocum` instead of `cd ocum` to enter `Documents`.

So the correct commands chain in `.zshrc` is

```
# load + start compinit
autoload -U compinit && compinit

# automatic cd into directory
setopt autocd

# correct if completion is no possible
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _approximate
```